# How to show $L_t$ is a martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion under probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. Let $X_t$ be defined as follows.

$$\mathrm{d}X_t = a \mathrm{d}t + 2\sqrt{ X_t} \mathrm{d}W_t.$$

Also define: $$L_t = \exp\left(-\frac{k}{2}\int_0^t \sqrt{X_s}\mathrm{d}W_s-\frac{k^2}{8}\int_0^t X_s\mathrm{d}W_s\right).$$

How to show $L_t$ is a martingale? Is there a Leibnitz rule for Ito's lemma which can help write $\mathrm{d}L_t$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I suspect that the differential in the last integral is $\mathrm{d}s$ and not $\mathrm{d}W_s$. If this is true, then try to apply the Ito's lemma by writing $L_t = \exp(Y_t)$ for a suitable process $Y_t$.